# segmentation fault in C assign string to char

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char a="9jhjhi";
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

Why does this throw a segmentation fault? What happens behind the screens?

Comment: "...behind the screens?"...i love it.

Comment: As everyone mentioned, `a` must be of type `char*`. Also FYI, though `a` is pointer to the string literal, it cannot be used to modify the string literal it is pointing to in this example. Because, string literal is stored in the data section of the code. So, `a[0] = 'K';` isnot allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is initialized to a (cast to integer and truncated because `char` is 3 or 7 bytes too small) pointer that points to a char array (propably somewhere in ROM). What follows is undefined, but it's propably like this: When you pass it to `printf` with a `%s` in the format string, it takes the value of `a` (something in `0-255`) and 3 (or 7) unrelated bytes from the stack, gets some bogus address and wreaks havok by accessing someone else's memory.

Use `char *a = ...`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `char *a = "..."`.

`printf` when passed `%s` will run through a string looking for a `0`/`NULL` byte. In your case you are not assigning a string literal to `a`, and in fact your compiler should have thrown a warning that you were trying to initialize a `char` from a pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *a="9jhjhi";
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your error is that

```
char a="9jhjhi";
```

should be

```
char *a="9jhjhi";
```

What happens is undefined behavior - so anything could happen.

Your assigning a string literal to a char, so your `a` will contain a pointer(to the beginning of that string) converted to a char - whatever that'll be.

`%s` conversion in printf assumes you pass it a string, which must be a char* pointing to a sequence of chars ending with a 0 terminator. You passed it a char, which certainly does not meet those requirements, so it's quite undefined what'll happen - a crash could be common.

You should also return something from the main() method - it's declared to return an int after all.

Answer (score 1):

C does not have strings as in String b = new String();

C has arrays of type char.

So char a="123123" should be a character array.

You aren't using anything from stdlib.h in that code either so there is no reason to #include it.

Edit: yeah, what nos said too. An array name is a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
char *a = "9jhjhi";
```

If this compiles without warnings, your compiler settings are messed up. The warnings from gcc show plainly what's happening:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test.c:6: warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

The string literal is interpreted as a pointer, which is converted (and truncated) to a `char`.

Then the `char` is sent into `printf` as a number, but interpreted as a string. Since it's not null-terminated in any way, `printf` probably overruns memory when racing through that "string".

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `char a` without a pointer symbol, you are only allocating enough space on the stack for a single character.

Strings in C are represented by a `char` array, or a pointer to a `char` array, terminated by the null character `'\0'`. But if you use a literal string, the compiler takes care of all of that for you.

Here's how you can get your code to work, then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *a = "9jhjhi";
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're trying to save an entire string into a single char variable. Use char array (char[size]) instead. You may also want to terminate the string with "\0".

Comment: No, he certainly doesn't want to terminate the string with `"\0"`. C string constants automatically have a nul byte at the end.

Answer (score 0):

**You could remove this error in two ways.**

1.char * p="karthik A"

2.char [ ]p="karthik A"

Comment: I think you meant `char p[] = "karthik A"`